# Como aplicar herencia en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando en una app de escritorio Windows Forms, utilizo Visual Studio 2015, Entity Framework enfoque code-firts.

El tema es el siguiente: Tengo unas tablas como: Compras, Ventas, TipoOperaciones y Movimientos.

En TipoOperacoines registro los siguientes datos: Venta, Compra, Consignacion, Promocion, Premio, Donacion, etc y esta esta relacionada con Movimientos.

He relacionado Ventas y Compras a Movimientos, pero VentaId y CompraId en Movimientos son una relación opcional(quiere decir que permite nulos).
[image: Registrar Inventarios]

Muestro un modelo de datos por que el UML que tengo es un poco extenso. La pregunta es ¿Como puedo aplicar herencia en este caso?, ojo utilizo **Entity Framework code-firts**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir la herencia puedes usar el campo `TipoOperacionId` como discriminador.

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Herencia - Tabla por jerarquía - Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/entity-frameworkcode-first-herencia.html)

en el articulo veras como se define un campo `Type` que cumple esta funcion.

En el mapping defines la herencia indicando el campo que permitira definir el tipo de la entidad, este valor puede ser numerico.

```
Map<EmployeeInternal>(x => x.Requires("Type")
                             .HasValue("I")
                             .HasColumnType("char")
                              .HasMaxLength(1));

Map<EmployeeExternal>(x => x.Requires("Type")
                              .HasValue("E"));
```

Un detalle es que a pesar que en tu caso derfines una tabla de tipos, vas a tener que indicar de forma fija en codigo que valor discriminador representa cada tipo en concreto.

Tambien vas a tener que definir las clases para cada tipo que soportes.

```
public class Movimiento
{
    public string Usuario {get;set;}
    public DateTime Fecha {get;set;}
}

public class MovimientoVenta : Movimiento
{
    public int? VentaId {get;set;}
    public Venta Venta {get;set;}
}

public class MovimientoCompra : Movimiento
{
    public int? CompraId {get;set;}
    public Compra Compra {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hola Leandro, en Compras tendría que poner esto public virtual ICollection<MovimientoCompra> MovimientoCompras { get; set; }

Comment: si quieres navegar desde las compras a los movimientos de este tipo entonces si

Comment: Si tengo UsuarioId en Venta y en Compras entonces ya no necesito poner UsuarioId en Movimiento?

Comment: pero si tienes el usuarioid en ambas clases hijas entonces lo correcto seria moverlo a la clase padre. Salvo que el usuario se defina en una de las clases hijas, en ese caso si seria particular de esa clase y no de la base